# Archive email to selfhosted cloud

Tags: backup, email, software-recommendation, archive

Our users have a very small mailbox. Increasing it's size is out of the question and they're using only iPhones and iPads.

There is a big possibility of them losing/destroying their devices (don't ask) so I do not want to archive their email on the device.

Is there any way for me to archive to a selfhosted cloud or something similar?

Comment: You might have better luck on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). Do you have any information on the email server? Check out [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org) if you wanna host your own version of the cloud.

Comment: Also, if the mail service they use is an IMAP or Exchange server, everything is kept on the server anyway unless an email is explicitly deleted. And regular backups can keep intentional deletion down to a minimum.